# how to add entity to CollisionGroup in realitykit

Tags: ios, collision, arkit, mask, realitykit

How do I include an entity in a collision group?

When I use func `raycast(...)` in RealityKit, the parameter `mask` defines: "A collision mask that you can use to prevent collisions with certain objects."

`mask` is `CollisionGroup`, how do I include my entity in the `CollisionGroup`? I want to use it prevent collisions with certain objects.

> `raycast(origin: SIMD3<Float>, direction: SIMD3<Float>, length: Float = 100, query: CollisionCastQueryType = .all, mask: CollisionGroup = .all, relativeTo referenceEntity: Entity? = nil) -> [CollisionCastHit]`

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the entity's collision component, you have the option of setting the collision group.

Any entity that conforms to [HasCollision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hascollision) has a `collision` variable that allows you to manipulate the [CollisionComponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/collisioncomponent). It is through the CollisionComponent that you can manipulate the [CollisionFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/collisionfilter) and set the `group` an entity belongs to and the `mask` of entities it can collide with.